# How can I create a MongoEngine document with referenced documents that are already in the database?

Tags: flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I already have a class of documents stored in my (Flask-MongoEngine) database, and **I already have their unique id**. My actual example is more complicated, but let's say it looks like this:

```
class Stuff(Document):
    stuffstuff = StringField()
```

I'd like to make a collection of Stuff instances from Stuffs already in my database. Let's say I want to make a new instance of the class below from Stuff instances currently in my database.

```
class StuffsCollection(Document):
    lotsofstuffs = ListField(ReferenceField(Stuff))
```

In the [ReferenceField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=referencefield) documentation, it looks like the only way to create a StuffsCollection instance is to first create instances of Stuff, then pass them in as keyword arguments. For example:

```
a_thing = Stuff(stuffstuff="here's a thing")
a_thing.save()
some_things = StuffsCollection(lotsofstuffs=[a_thing])
some_things.save()
```

**Since I already have the unique ids that reference my Stuff instances, can I just tell MongoEngine to use those existing Stuffs as keyword arguments in a new StuffsCollection?** It seems like this would be more efficient than querying the database for each document, then creating a new instance of that document, then passing each into my new ListField.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `DBRef` objects:

```
from bson import DBRef, ObjectId

a_id = ObjectId('somevalidid')
a_ref = DBRef('stuff', a_id)

some_things = StuffsCollection(lotsofstuffs=[a_ref])
some_things.save()
```

MongoEngine stores a `ReferenceField` using either `DBRef` or `ObjectID`. The `'stuff'` argument to `DBRef` will simply be ignored if the field is configured with `dbref=False`. Otherwise, this must be the name of the collection for the `Stuff` objects.

However, you need to pass `DBRef` objects to the constructor in both cases because of the way the validation is implemented in `ReferenceField`.

Comment: Thanks very much! One more thing: how would I pass existing documents (for which I already know the id, and which inherit from the base Document like the Stuff class above) into a new StuffsCollection as *embedded documents* rather than Referenced documents?

Comment: With embedded documents, you need to pass the whole document with all its data to the new container, so there is no way around fetching it from the DB first.